# Angular still submits the form even when I return false in the handler

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have something like the following:

HTML template:

```
<form [action]='endpoint' method="post" target="my_iframe" #confirmForm (ngSubmit)="submitConfirmation()">
  <button type="submit" (click)="confirmForm.submit()">Submit</button>
</form>

<iframe name="my_iframe"></iframe>
```

And in the component:

```
submitConfirmation() {
    return false;
}
```

I've also tried throwing an error:

```
submitConfirmation() {
    throw Error('test');
    return false;
}
```

No matter what I do, the form still submits! Every resource I found online tells me that if I return false in the submit handler, the form will not be submitted. Could this have something to do with the iframe? (it's required for reasons I won't get into). The method definitely runs, I have checked and triple checked.

On a related note, do I actually need `(click)="confirmForm.submit()` on the submit button?

EDIT: I just tried removing `(click)="confirmForm.submit()` and now I'm even more confused! When I removed that binding, the button still works, the method `submitConfirmation` still gets called, but now the form fails to submit regardless of whether I return false or not.

Comment: Please quote these online resources.

Comment: @NicholasK Literally everything you find if you google the question I asked. And how is that relevant anyway? The question is how do I prevent the form submission? Clearly the approach outlined above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to `preventDefault` on the triggering event. Your component class should look like:

```js
submitConfirmation(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // other stuff
}
```

To use that will require passing in the `$event` parameter from the component template:

```html
<form ... (ngSubmit)="submitConfirmation($event)">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

No need for `(click)="confirmForm.submit()`. Buttons within a form will default to a type of `submit` (explicitly set `type="button"` otherwise) and this will trigger the `(ngSubmit)` event.